# Ejecutar emit de Socket.io en controller de api rest express.js

Tags: nodejs, express, socket.io

Tal como dice el titulo, tengo una api rest  de prueba en node y express, y lo que quiero hacer es:
configurar el socket y luego poder emitir eventos desde una funcion especifica de algun controlador. Este codigo no me arroja ningun error, pero el cliente no puede conectarse al socket. Este es mi *Server.js* en el cual tengo configurado mi servidor:

```
const express = require('express')

const { dbConnect } = require('../config/db')

const cors = require('cors')

const io = require('./socket')


class Server {
    constructor() {

        this.app = express()

        this.server = require("http").createServer(this.app); //añadi esto para poder ejecutar socket.io
        this.io = require("socket.io")(this.server, { //añadi esto para poder ejecutar socket.io
            cors: {
                origin: "*",
            },
        });

        this.port = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 3000

        // 1- middleware
        this.middlewares()

        // 2- connect DB
        this.connectDB()

        // 3- routes
        this.routes()

    }

    async connectDB() {
        await dbConnect()
    }

    middlewares() {
        this.app.use(cors())
        this.app.use((req, res, next) => { // añado _this.io_ al response para poder usarlo en cualquier controlador
            res.io = this.io
            next()
        });

        this.app.use(express.json())

        this.app.use(express.static('public'))
    }

    routes() {
        this.app.use('/api/example', require('./modules/example/example.router')) // router que me lleva al controlador que se indica mas abajo
    }

    listen() {

        // socket connection
        io.on("connection", (socket) => { //añadi esto para poder ejecutar socket.io
            console.log(socket.id);
        })

        this.app.listen(this.port, () => {
            console.log('Conectado...', this.port)
        })
    }
}

module.exports = Server;
```

Este es el controlador conde voy a usarlo:

```
const { request, response } = require('express');
const { getExamples } = require('./example.queries');

const all = async (req = request, res = response) => {

    const data = await getExamples()

    res.io.emit("mensaje", {
        message: "hello from controller"
    });
    return res.status(200).json({
        msg: 'Este es un mensaje de la funcion all del controller',
        data
    });
}

module.exports = {
    all,

}
```

y este es el cliente de ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.7.2/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <title>Reciever</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script>
        const socket = io('http://localhost:3000')
        socket.on('mensaje', (data) => {
            console.log(data)
        })

    </script>
</body>

</html>

</html>
```